# How to remove a package safely

Tags: apt

I was trying out different package managers, I did

```
apt-get install aptitude && apt-get install apt
```

Then I didn't like `apt` so I did

```
apt-get remove apt
```

It warned me that you are about to do something harmful, please type the phrase "Yes, do as I say!"

I did that because I had read on StackExchange before that `apt-get remove` only removes files, not any configurations, so it was safer than `apt-get purge`, and also I thought it was `apt` only that I was removing.

Then I tried installing other software, when it said

```
bash: /usr/bin/apt-get: No such file or directory
```

It removed my `apt-get` `apt-cache` and other packages.

- Why?
- And how do I install apt-get and similar packages back again?
- How to not do a similar mistake in the future while using `apt-get remove` or `apt-get purge` by safely removing only what I installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `apt` package contains, among other things,

```
/usr/bin/apt
/usr/bin/apt-cache
/usr/bin/apt-cdrom
/usr/bin/apt-config
/usr/bin/apt-get
/usr/bin/apt-key
/usr/bin/apt-mark
```

When you removed the package, you removed all those files too.

To re-install, you’ll need to retrieve the packages. They’re probably still in your local cache, so

```
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/apt_*deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libapt-pkg*deb
```

should restore a working configuration. If it doesn’t, you’ll need to download the packages from your distribution’s repositories, *e.g.* for Kali you’d need the `apt` and `libapt-pkg5.0` packages from the [`apt` pool](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/apt/).

To avoid such situations in the future, don’t confirm harmful actions unless you *really* know what you’re doing. You can check what will be removed when you remove a package by listing its contents with `dpkg -L`, *e.g.* in this case `dpkg -L apt` (with the package installed).